# при валидации формы сравнить два значения инпут

Tags: jquery

Есть форма. в ней таблица. пользователь вводит значения в таблицу и может **добавлять строки в таблицу по кнопке "Добавить".** В таблице есть колонка "Доступное количество" и "Количество". Так вот при валидации нужно, чтобы поле "Количество" было заполнено и "Количество" было <= "Доступное количество"

```
<td><input name="aval_quant_1" type="text"></td> //Доступное колличество

<td><input name="quantity_1" type="text" </td>  // Колличество
```

Моя функция jQuey:

```
function validateForm() {
var ch=true, q, aval_q;
$('input[name^="quantity"]').each(function(i,v){ 
ch = ch && '' != $(v).val(); 
 });
$('input[name^="quantity"] ,input[name^="aval_quantity"]').each(function(i,v){ 
  q = $('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
  aval_q=$('input[name^="aval_quantity"]').val();
 });
 if(ch != true)
 {
    alert("Поле Количество должно быть заполнено");
    return false;
 }
 else if (q > aval_q){
    alert("Поле Количество не может быть больше Доступного кол-ва");
    return false;
 }
 else {return true;}    
 }
```

На заполненность проверяется правильно во всех строках, но не сравнивает значения

Comment: Не могли бы вы прикрепить код в jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас, указано `$('input[name^="aval_quantity"]').val();`

Тогда как `input` доступного количества в разметке имеет имя `aval_quant_1`. Замените на `$('input[name^="aval"]').val();`. В `each` соответственно тоже следует поправить.

Comment: блиин! точно. Респект